# In ES how to use synonyms file for term filters but also for wildcard queries?

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

I was using synonyms in elasticsearch now my mappings are given below

```
"settings": {
        "index": {
          "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
              "synonym": {
                "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                "filter": ["synonym"]
              }
            },
            "filter": {
              "synonym": {
                "type": "synonym",
                "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      mappings : {
        places_city: {
          properties:{
            city         : {"type" : "string", "index": "analyzed", "analyzer": "synonym"},
          }
        }
      }
```

Now my problem is that if i am using filter on places_city.city i mean 'city' field than there is no problem everything is working fine but the problem here is that whenever i am trying to use query or wildcard query on 'city' field ES is not returning anything so what is the thing i am doing wrong i think problem is in my mapping so if anyone know anything about this please help i wanna use my 'city' field as both filter as well wildcard query.

**Update- Query i am using is given below**

```
bool: {
                "disable_coord": true,
                "must": [
                  {
                    "constant_score": { // here i am using this because to remove tf/idf factors from my scoring
                      boost: 1.02,
                      "query": {
                        query_string: {
                          query: location_search,
                          fields: ['places_city.city'],
        //                 boost: 4
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ], 
                "should": [
                  {
                    "constant_score": {
                      boost: 10,
                      "query": {
                        query_string: {
                          query: curr_city,
                          fields: ['places_city.city'],
                    //     boost: 8
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
```

Comment: could you post the query you are trying?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 pls have a relook ??

Comment: This could be due to `query_string` query. see this [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-word-synonyms.html#_synonyms_and_the_query_string_query) _new york_ will be passed as two tokens _new_ and _york_. Try using `match` query and if you still dont get results, pls post sample synonym file and I will try on my machine

Comment: actually term filter is searching for 'new' and 'york' but not for 'new york' ??

Comment: also when i am searching for yor* using Wildcard then ES is not returning anything but when i am searching for Yor* using same query then it is returning 'New York' actually i wanna know how should i define mappings so that for both lowercase and uppercase my wildcard query or query string return the appropriate string ??

Comment: please have a look at this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761388/in-es-how-to-write-mappings-so-that-to-use-wildcard-query-for-both-lowecase-as-w