# In ES how to write mappings so that to use wildcard query for both lowercase as well as uppercase?

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

Hello all i am facing two problems in ES

1. I have a 'city' 'New York' in ES now i want to write a term filter such that if given string exactly matches "New York" then only it returns but what is happening is that when my filter matches "New" OR "York" for both it returns "New York" but it is not returning anything for "New York" my mapping is given below please tell me which analyzer or tokenizer should i use inside mapping

Here are the settings and mapping:

```
"settings": {
        "index": {
          "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
              "synonym": {
                "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                "filter": ["synonym"]
              }
            },
            "filter": {
              "synonym": {
                "type": "synonym",
                "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      mappings : {
        "restaurant" : {
          properties:{
            address         : {
                properties:{
                    city         : {"type" : "string", "analyzer": "synonym"},
                }
            }
          }
        }
```

2. Second problem is that when i am trying to use wildcard query on lowercase example "new*" then ES is not returning not anything but when i am trying to search uppercase example "New*" now it is returning "New York" now i in this second case i want to write my city mappings such that when i search for lowercase or uppercase for both ES returns the same thing i have seen ignore case and i have set it to false inside synonyms but still i am not able to search for both lowercase and uppercases.

   ```
        "synonym": {
               "type": "synonym",
               "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt",
               "ignore_case": true   // See here 
             }
   ```

Comment: how is your synonym file? is it like `ny, nyc , new york city => new york` or `ny, nyc ,new york city, new york` because the way you specify synonyms will have implications

Comment: new york is not there in synonyms file

Comment: @amanverma provide the content of `synonyms.txt` file relevant to the `New York` search.

Comment: no synonyms file has nothing to do with ne york i have different places there leme show you what it contains                                          mumbai, bombay
calcutta, kolkata
puducherry, pondicherry
Bangalore, Bengaluru

Answer (score 1):

I believe you didn't provide enough details, but hoping that my attempt will generate questions from you, I will post what I believe it should be a step forward:

The **mapping**:

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym": {
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [
              "synonym"
            ]
          },
          "keyword_lowercase": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt",
            "ignore_case": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "restaurant": {
      "properties": {
        "address": {
          "properties": {
            "city": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "synonym",
              "fields": {
                "raw": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "raw_ignore_case": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "keyword_lowercase"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Test data:**

```
POST /test/restaurant/1
{
  "address": {"city":"New York"}
}
POST /test/restaurant/2
{
  "address": {"city":"new york"}
}
```

Query for the **first problem**:

```
GET /test/restaurant/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "address.city.raw": "New York"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query for the **second problem**:

```
GET /test/restaurant/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "address.city.raw_ignore_case:new*"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what will be the result if i query for new york for the second problem solution will it return New York or not ??

Comment: also you dont get it actualy according to your solution if i want to filter for "New York" but also wanna use synonym file there how can i use that i mean because you have set .raw to not_analyzed so it will not look in synonym file for term filter ??

Comment: For the second problem, yes. For synonym it depends in what you want to do with it. What do you want to match? Give examples of input and desired output.

Comment: suppose i want to apply term filter with filter string as nyc but also i am having nyc as New york in my synonyms.txt so this filter will return New York but according to your solution it will not get it ??

Comment: When you use `term` filter the text that you use in your filter will not be analyzed. So whatever you put there (lowercase, uppercase) it will be matched exactly as is. This means that your index needs to have the data available to match this (both lowercase and uppercase for all the synonyms). I would suggest looking for something else rather than `term` **OR** lowercase everything that goes into your `term` filter so that you know that you want to match lowercase with lowercase in the index.

Comment: actually i solved my second isssue by using tokenizer 'keyword' inside my synonyms because of which i am able to use term filter on exact match :) thanks a lot anyways for your help actually i am facing a problem can you tell me that while using synonyms when i am trying to use query_string then ES is returning nothing but when i use wildcard query it throws results why did this happen ??

Comment: can you please tell me inside mappings in city you have define analyzer : "synonym" again why ??

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur that's your own mapping. Look at the original post.

Comment: but why do we need that mapping if we are going to make two different mapping fields .raw and the other one dont you think its unnecessary ???